# Sort Column on clicking sort icon in another Column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, bootstrap-4

In my case I have 3 columns 'Name', 'Age', and 'Column3'. In Column 1 and Column 2, I have displayed username and age respectively.

[image: Data Table]

I want to sort age column by clicking on sort icon of third column.

I have used [Data Tables](https://datatables.net/)

Comment: Users will click on the icon column with the intention of sorting by Age? That seems very unexpected to me. Why not make the icon column not sortable?

Comment: Actually, For Age column I have managed to hide sort icon using `"columnDefs": [
                { "targets": 0, "orderable": true },
                { "targets": 1, "orderable": false },
                { "targets": 2, "orderable": false }

            ]`
now the user feels that there is only two column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DataTables column numbering starts at 0, so Name is 0, Age is 1, and the icon column is 2.

Here you are saying when column 2 (icons) is clicked, use the data in column 1 (Age) as the data to sort by.

```
$("#myTable").dataTable({
  "columnDefs": [
    { "orderData": [ 1 ], "targets": 2 }
  ]
});
```

If you want to remove sorting for the icons columns (recommended), change `orderable` to false.

```
$("#myTable").dataTable({
  "columnDefs": [
    { "orderable": false, "targets": 2 }
  ]
});
```